# Ruby on Rails: configure web_console in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, config, web-console

I am using the web_console gem and I would like to add some IPs to the whitelist. For reasons that would probably go to far to explain, can't simply add something to the `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/development.rb`. However I can create an initializer `config/initializers/`.
I simple tried this in `config/initializers/99-webconsole.rb`, but while the file is loaded (--> debug message is shown), the web console does not seem to pick up my settings.

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '10.10.0.0/16'
  p "Debug: this is loaded."
end
```

I assume it's related to some kind of race condition? Providing the same line in `config/environments/development.rb` works, but as said, I sadly can not change that file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this code https://github.com/rails/web-console/blob/e3dcf4c588af526eafcf1ce9413e62d846599538/lib/web_console/railtie.rb#L59

maybe there is a code in your initializer that configuring `config.web_console.permissions`, so your `whitelisted_ips` config is ignored

`whitelisted_ips` is also deprecated

and have you checked that you are using v4.2.0, the permissions was buggy and fixed by this commit https://github.com/rails/web-console/commit/6336c89385b58e88b2661ea3dc42fe28651d6296

Comment: I did, yes. No success either. As said, it works if I put the setting in the `environments/developemnt.rb` but not in an initializer.

Comment: please check my updated answer